# Angluarjs using buttons to filter an array

Tags: angularjs, button, ng-show

I'm trying to get an app to use buttons to look at properties of recipes in an array and hide certain recipes based on restrictions. I know it's probably a simple problem to experienced coders, but I'm still learning. I know my code is messy and incomplete, I was just using it to try to get my thoughts in order. Lots of placeholders. Apologies.

PS if you've seen my previous questions, I was instructed to abandon that set of filters and simplify the app to use ng-show/hide instead.

edit:

html:

```
<div>
  <h2>Restrictions</h2>
  <button ng-click="toggleNuts">Nuts</button>
  <button ng-click="toggleWheat">Wheat</button>

</div>
```

ng-repeat:

```
<div>
  <h2>Restrictions</h2>
  <button ng-click="toggleNuts">Nuts</button>
  <button ng-click="toggleWheat">Wheat</button>

</div>
```

recipe.js:

```
var foods = [{
      type: 'vegetarian',
      name: 'recipe's name',
      restrictions: [
       'nuts',
       'dairy',
       ],
}]
```

plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/lCNSBlUt8X3wDT8Tsbkd?p=preview

Comment: plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/lCNSBlUt8X3wDT8Tsbkd

Comment: sidenote: i have tried many different tutorial solutions but none have worked out. i took out my old attempts and put the placeholders in their place.

Comment: What *exactly* isn't working?  You don't really describe your problem in this question; rather you describe your program's requirements.  Also, you haven't listed any code to troubleshoot in the question, instead you listed in the comments a link to your entire code source, which it is unlikely that anyone will take the time to study in detail.  I highly suggest reading how to create a [mcve] and editing your question.

Comment: @AndriesGous, do you want to search only when you click a button?

Comment: @Abhilash indeed i need it to hide the recipes as the buttons are clicked

Comment: @Claies I do apologize. I posted the whole thing because I do not know what part of the code it is that is tripping it up. My problem is that with every solution I've tried the buttons end up either doing nothing, or the mere addition of the buttons bombs out the entire ng-repeat and nothing is displayed.

Comment: I understand that it can be tough to know what to ask when you aren't sure what's wrong in the first place, but that's all the more reason to take the approach described in the help article I posted.  Start off small, with only *one* button, and a much smaller data set, and when the logic for that button becomes a problem, post that chunk of code; once you have one button working, the others will work, using the same pattern, with more data added.

Comment: As it stands now, you are asking people to go into a crumbled house pick through the rubble to figure out why it fell over.

Comment: @Claies I understand. I'll quickly do that and post the new chunk if that's okay?

Comment: of course it's ok.  We *want* to help people figure out coding issues, but to be helpful, we need to know what to focus on.

Comment: see that's a **much** better question, and it seems to have gotten you an answer.

Comment: @AbhilashPA could you have a look at it please?

Comment: i found this tutorial https://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/15202/ but i cant seem to get it to apply to my app. i've tried editing each of the variables but it doesnt seem to pick it up. i dont know if my database is formatted incorrectly or what?

Comment: @AndriesGous, Please check my answer.

Comment: @AbhilashPA please check my other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34988543/changing-checkboxes-into-animatable-buttons-with-javascript

Comment: @Claies if you can please check it too, I'd be grateful

Answer (score 0):

I edited your plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/rCNaOx9JMgkwVgG9Tn3M?p=preview

I used lodash librairy to handle the filter in my function toggle.

```
$scope.toggle = function(restriction) {  
    $scope.products = _.filter(foods, function( food ) {
      return _.includes(food.restrictions, restriction);
    });
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: that does bring me much closer yes, thank you so much! however, it is kind of doing the opposite of what i need. i need it to hide the recipes with the restrictions corresponding to the buttons. also, i need them to be able to stack and toggle. essentially (and i realize now i should've been clearer, apologies) i need them to work like checkboxes. is that possible?

Comment: @Claies does that make sense?

Comment: I managed to get it to hide instead of show, but still no luck with toggling or stacking

Answer (score 0):

I have done your requirement and you can check the result here. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/a4e1RjVEjsjtoGvFS6Q3?p=info)

To achieve this, I have created a new filter, `restrict`.

```
.filter('restrict', function() {
      return function(foods, filterNuts, filterWheats) {
        var filtered = [];
       debugger;
        angular.forEach(foods, function(food) {
          if(filterNuts){
              if (angular.lowercase(food.restrictions).indexOf( "nuts" ) != -1) {
              filtered.push(food);
            }
          }
          if(filterWheats){
              if (angular.lowercase(food.restrictions).indexOf( "wheat" ) != -1) {
              filtered.push(food);
            }
          }

        });
        return filtered;
      };
    }
);
```

And I have applied this filter to our `ng-repeat` in the html,

```
<div class="results" ng-repeat="food in products| restrict:filterNuts:filterWheat"> </div>
```

Hope this will help you...

**Please feel free to ask any doubt on this !!!**