# changing checkboxes into animatable buttons with javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, button

I'm building a practice app. I've got a working filter system using checkboxes and radio buttons. I need a way to replace them with buttons that I can animate. For my plunk I'll use buttons with text, but then offline I'll replace them with images. Here's a sample of my work:

HTML

```
        <h2>Type</h2>
        <label class="btns">
            <input type="radio" name="vegMeat" value="" ng-model="type.searchVeg" ng-checked="true">All
        </label>
            <label class="btns">
                <input type="radio" name="vegMeat" value="veg" ng-model="type.searchVeg">Vegetarian
            </label>
            <label class="btns">
                <input type="radio" name="vegMeat" value="meat" ng-model="type.searchVeg">Meat
            </label>

    </div>
```

JavaScript

```
  .filter('searchType', function() {
return function(foods, search) {
  var filtered = [];
  if (!search) {
    return foods;
  }
  angular.forEach(foods, function(food) {

    if (angular.lowercase(food.type).indexOf(angular.lowercase(search)) != -1) {
      filtered.push(food);
    }
  });
  return filtered;
};
```

sample plunk
https://plnkr.co/edit/xk1VcCfAsVknyahux4fw?p=preview

PS I know mine is not the most efficient way of doing it, but I'm still a beginner. The buttons are my main concern but if anyone does have suggestions on how to improve the code itself, please feel free to provide an example. This is just a sample of my plunk. My full one has another 5 sets of buttons and many more recipes.

Comment: if you put your label after your input, you can style it with css, without the need for js: http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-checkbox-styles

Comment: yeah i can do that, but my instructor wants normal buttons like youd find on a proper app. does that make sense? thank you though

Comment: ultimately he wants me to use icons as buttons instead of text

Comment: I continue to be confused by what you are trying to accomplish.  Are you suggesting that you want a group of buttons that act like radio selects, and another group of buttons that acts like checkboxes?  I'm assuming you also want to style them so that you know which ones are selected?

Comment: @Claies that is exactly right yes. sorry was otherwise engaged last week and was unable to work on this